# Simple code with some errors

Tags: java, dice

this is nothing complicated I just need to know what I am incorrect on. I was this program to display the dice and the roll numbers. after that I want it to add them and if they roll over 15 its a win, if not its a loss. This program is just a small exercise from a book we are using in class if anyone is wondering what this is. I am receiving illegal start of expressions and reached end while parsing.

```
public class BradySkuza36
    {
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
int roll1, roll2, roll3, roll4, roll5;




roll1 = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*6);
roll2 = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*6);
roll3 = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*6);
roll4 = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*6);
roll5 = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*6);
System.out.println("\nYou rolled: " + roll1 + " " + roll2 + " " + roll3 + " " + roll4 + " " + roll5);
showDice(roll1);
showDice(roll2);
showDice(roll3);
showDice(roll4);
showDice(roll5);



    if(rollAdd >= 15)
    {
        System.out.println("You win!);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry maybe next time.");
    }
}
public static void showDice( int roll )
{
    System.out.println("+   +");
if ( roll == 1 )
{
    System.out.println("|   |");
    System.out.println("| o |");
    System.out.println("|   |");
}
else if ( roll == 2 )
{
    System.out.println("|o  |");
    System.out.println("|   |");
    System.out.println("|  o|");
}
else if ( roll == 3 )
{
    System.out.println("|o  |");
    System.out.println("| o |");
    System.out.println("|  o|");
}
else if ( roll == 4 )
{
    System.out.println("|o o|");
    System.out.println("|   |");
    System.out.println("|o o|");
}
else if ( roll == 5 )
{
    System.out.println("|o o|");
    System.out.println("| o |");
    System.out.println("|o o|");
}
else if ( roll == 6 )
{
    System.out.println("|o o|");
    System.out.println("|o o|");
    System.out.println("|o o|");
}
    System.out.println("+   +");
}

public static void rollAdd(int added)
{
    added = roll1 + roll2 + roll3 + roll4 + roll5;
}

}

}
```

Comment: You're probably missing a curly or a non-curly bracket somewhere. Judging by the indentation of your code, this is no surprise.

Comment: The variable `rollAdd` is undefined; `if (rollAdd >= 15) {`, which I assume is suppose to be calling the `rollAdd` method, into which you should be passing the values `roll1, `roll2`, `roll3`, `roll4`, `roll5` values and returning the result. You can modify the value of method parameters so your `rollAdd` method won't work the way you think it will and I believe theres's an extra `}` at the end of the file

Comment: There is several issue with your code (missing quote, undeclared variable, inaccessible variable, ...) which all can be fixed with a simple IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several small problems in your code.

First of all ,you have an extra `}` at the end.Remove it. Secondly,call `rolladd` using `rolladd(roll1,roll2,roll3,roll4,roll5)` and change the method to

```
public static int rollAdd(int roll1,int roll2,int roll3,int roll4,int roll5)
{   
 int added = roll1 + roll2 + roll3 + roll4 + roll5;
 return added;
 }
```

Lastly,you are missing a `"` in

```
System.out.println("You win!);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did your homework

```
public class Help {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int roll1, roll2, roll3, roll4, roll5;

    roll1 = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 6);
    roll2 = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 6);
    roll3 = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 6);
    roll4 = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 6);
    roll5 = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 6);
    System.out.println("\nYou rolled: " + roll1 + " " + roll2 + " " + roll3
            + " " + roll4 + " " + roll5);
    showDice(roll1);
    showDice(roll2);
    showDice(roll3);
    showDice(roll4);
    showDice(roll5);

    int rollAdd = roll1 + roll2 + roll3 + roll4 + roll5;

    if (rollAdd >= 15) {
        System.out.println("You win!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Sorry maybe next time.");
    }
}

public static void showDice(int roll) {
    System.out.println("+   +");
    if (roll == 1) {
        System.out.println("|   |");
        System.out.println("| o |");
        System.out.println("|   |");
    } else if (roll == 2) {
        System.out.println("|o  |");
        System.out.println("|   |");
        System.out.println("|  o|");
    } else if (roll == 3) {
        System.out.println("|o  |");
        System.out.println("| o |");
        System.out.println("|  o|");
    } else if (roll == 4) {
        System.out.println("|o o|");
        System.out.println("|   |");
        System.out.println("|o o|");
    } else if (roll == 5) {
        System.out.println("|o o|");
        System.out.println("| o |");
        System.out.println("|o o|");
    } else if (roll == 6) {
        System.out.println("|o o|");
        System.out.println("|o o|");
        System.out.println("|o o|");
    }
    System.out.println("+   +");
}
```

}

1. Your `System.out.println();` was missing a `"`
2. You didnot create a variable named `rollAdd`
3. All variables defined in `rollAdd()` method are not declared
4. You have an extra `}` at the end

Answer (score 0):

1. Please fix your syntax problems: Curly bracket at the end; double apostrophe on line 26
2. You have your roll1 to roll5 variables defined in the main function scope, you need them to be defined in a class for `rollAdd` function to be able to use them.
3. The overall logics on rollAdd function, which *doesn't* return anything is wrong.

Sincerely, I would recommend revisiting your programming topics all over again.